# Recreating fragment's view when paging tabs in Action Bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I use ActionBarSherlock compatibility library and experience a strange behavior when paging between tabs of Action Bar. Each tab contains a simple Fragment, nothing special. I observed that fragment's `onCreateView` method is called too often even though there is no screen orientation change. It looks like some kind of pre-caching. I have three tabs there, when the activity is created, the `onCreateView` is called only for the first two fragments. The last fragment doesn't create view until I page one step forward. The same behavior occurs when paging from the last tab to the first.

Has anybody any idea why this occurs? I would assume creating all views at once, when the parent activity finishes its creating. I don't want to create views again and again, there are no changes in the fragments, they are static. It has no sense and causes paging to be sluggish a bit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few hours I found what's happening there. ViewPager has a default setting DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES which sets the maximum number of views (fragments in my case) to be stored in the view container of ViewPager.  It is obviously some kind of resource optimization; invisible views can be thrown away and restored when needed.

There is nothing easier then change this value by `setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)` setter which I overlooked.

Comment: Thanks.Your answer proved helpful to me in a different way.I had a custom layout into which views were being added dynamically.I had 4 screens. When i swipe to the 4th screen and return to the first the my custom layout was not getting displayed properly with the views that i had added dynamically.Although not a solution that directly addresses the issue,this fixes the issue.upvoted

Answer (score 0):

I think it was done consciously to increase user experience.
The same way ViewPager from compatibility lib is implemented.

Anyway, sources are available.