# Fragment does not show when switching between tabs on TabHost

Tags: android

i have a tab host  with three tabs  ,two of them have activities that contain the same   subclass of Fragment (i am testing the behaviour of the fragment on different positions) .So when i switch from the first tab to the second the Fragment shows succesfully ,but when i come back to the fisrt nothing is on  screen .May be it is a problem of lifecycle ,can someone help me to figure out a solution to  that ?

for informations,i am working with android.support.v4 package .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and asked following question here on SO:

[Recreating fragment's view when paging tabs in Action Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778092/recreating-fragments-view-when-paging-tabs-in-action-bar)

I am quite sure you can solve your issue by setting off screen page limit to 3:

```
yourPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

Although the mentioned setting can help I am sure you don't create views of your fragments properly.

I can't say anything specific without seeing a code, but keep in mind that if you do not set the off screen page limit to some specific value, all fragments except the current and next one are completely destroyed and created "on demand" when you go to the next page...

Also keep in mind that if you use setRetainInstance(true) and rely on some initialization in onCreate method it probably will not work because this method isn't called in this case